# Socketio doesnt work with webpack but works with CDN

Tags: webpack, socket.io, feathersjs

I have a feathersjs app which uses socketio for the transport protocol. On my client side I use webpack to bundle the app, but I'm having issues with the socketio client connecting to the server. I'm not sure if this is a problem with Webpack, socketio or feathersjs.

The problem is when bundling socketio with webpack, the socket.io-client always timesout after 5000ms. But if I use a CDN version of socketio it connects fine.

```
// Timeout when imported in app.js
import io from 'socket.io-client';

// Connects fine when using a CDN in template.html
<script src="//unpkg.com/socket.io-client@^2.3.0/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I've made a very simple demo repository showing my issue:

https://github.com/jrj2211/feathers-socketio-issue

If you run it with "npm start" and go to "localhost:3030", clicking signin will give the error "Timeout of 5000ms exceeded calling create on authentication".

[image]

Going into the app/app.js file and commenting out the "import io from 'socket.io-client';" and relaunching the app will show "success".

I have checked that both the CDN and npm version of socketio.client are both 2.3.

From this I believe its something to do with my webpack setup but I'm not sure how to fix it.

### Relevant code:

**app.js**

```
import feathers from '@feathersjs/client';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import auth from '@feathersjs/authentication-client';

const app = feathers();
app.io = io();

app.configure(feathers.socketio(app.io));
app.configure(feathers.authentication());

export default {
  client: app,
}
```

**template.html**

```
<html theme='light'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ZyPhox MRP</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <base href="/" target="_blank">

    <script src="//unpkg.com/socket.io-client@^2.3.0/dist/socket.io.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='message'></div>
    <input name='username' type='text' placeholder='Username'>
    <input name='password' type='password' placeholder='Password'>
    <input name='signin' type='submit' value='Signin'>
  </body>
</html>
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

// Plugins
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'index.js'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './app/template.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules(\/|\\)(?!(@feathersjs|debug))/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: ['source-map-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './app/'), path.resolve('./node_modules')],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `socket.io-client` version you installed (and saved to `package.json`) matches the server version. For Feathers 4 it should be `^2.3.0` (as you used in the CDN), for Feathers 5 it should be `^3.0.0` or later. Since there are breaking changes in Socket.io a mismatch in versions will only produce a timeout.

Comment: I did ensure that the version in the node_modules folder is 2.3.0 and doing a diff check on precompiled lib in the dist folder is identical to that on unpkg. Its only when importing through webpack that is timing out, so I'm guessing it has to be something with how I have webpack configured. I did start fresh projects twice to try and get this to work and everytime I have this issue.